# Control after changing format date Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to control a date after changing date format

```
df["Date start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date start"])
df["Date start"] = df["Date start"].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df = df[df["Date start"] > "01/01/2022"]
```

But I do have an error like this

```
UserWarning: Parsing '16/04/2012' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing.
  df["Date start"] = pd.to_datetime(fd["Date start"],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

How can I fix it?

Tried all these methods:

```
df["date start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date start"], format='%d/%m/%Y', dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df["date start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date start"], dayfirst=True)
df["date start"] = df["date start"].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for date comparison, make the date as yyyy-mm-dd (without or without hyphens). This ensures the dates being compared are in chronological order

when you have day as first in a date when comparing. it will group all months and all year with the day 1, before day 2 and so on

```
# inline conversion of date to yyyy-mm-dd (default) format and then comparing
# and filtering the result using LOC
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df["date start"], dayfirst=True) > "2022-01-01"]
```

Comment: Many thanks! This method worked!

Comment: I don't totally get it.
If I want to convert it I might do something like this

df["birthDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["birthDate"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

But when I export my excel file, I see the date with hours minutes and seconds